# dygraphs y2 axis overlap of y2 scale

Tags: dygraphs

How does one create extra space for the `y2-axis` label in `Dygraphs` ?

In all examples with y2 scale (digits > 3) will cause overlap of the label text.    I've tried CSS style, but nothing seems to secure extra needed space.

Thanks for the assist.

Answer (score 4):

You need to set the [`axisLabelWidth`](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#axisLabelWidth) option for the y2 axis:

```
new Dygraph(div, data, {
  axes: {
    y2: {
      axisLabelWidth: 100  // or whatever you want
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much!   Works like a charm.